# ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found. The referenced database link did not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have query in oracle 19c:

```
Select
col_a,
col_b,
col_c,
col_d
FROM view_a
UNION ALL
Select
col_a,
col_b,
col_c,
col_d
FROM view_b
```

View view_a and view_b have their own logic but view_a use db_link - db_a and view_b use db_link db_b.
Every select works fine separately but when i run it together by using union all i have error:

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
ORA-02063: preceding line from DB
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from db_b
```

The problem is that this db link exists, also select separately works fine.
What's more second select returns 0 rows.
What could be the problem?

Comment: It almost sounds like Oracle has rewritten it and sent work to the remote it shouldn't have. It would help if you included the view SQL that showed the links involved, and the execution plan for each half explained separately.

Comment: Sorry i can't deliver body of these views but you need to believe me. Funny fact is that even if i want to check explain plan i have error about this db link when i do it for select with union. Separately explains plans look really simple.

Comment: We can't help you with code you're not showing. A view is just a label for code, and it's that code that's running.

Comment: Looks like some user permissions. Is view_a and view_b created by the same user? Who is the owner of the db link? Who is executing the UNION ALL query? You need to add a little more context here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if works around the problem:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT /*+ no_merge materialize */ col_a,col_b,col_c,col_d FROM view_a),
     b AS (SELECT /*+ no_merge materialize */ col_a,col_b,col_c,col_d FROM view_b)
SELECT * FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM b
```

This should force the local database to drive the query and keep the two remote pieces separate. Still, there's an underlying problem, perhaps bug, that needs to be discovered, but this may help.